# Are compilers guaranteed to optimize recursive code generated by templates?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, c++11, recursion

Bjarne Stroustrup's [C++11 FAQ about templates](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#variadic-templates) contains following words:

> This is rather standard functional programming done at compile time.

Does that mean that [his example with `printf`](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#variadic-templates) should be node recursive after being compiled?  I simplified example a little bit, and all compilers with disabled optimization generate recursive code.  For example, here's [the output from `g++ -O2`](http://tinyurl.com/qc8hmpa), and it isn't recursive, but clang keeps it recursive no matter what.

What am I missing?

P.S. There was mistake of mine. In this example clang with optimization options compile code like all other - in a plain way (no recursion). But without optimisation - all still compile with recursion.

Comment: C and C++ are distinct languages, and templates are specific to C++. Note there's also a C11 Standard.

Comment: I am confused by your question. The sentence "this is functional programming done at compile time" applies to the structural description that variadic templates provide (it is, in your `printf` example, somewhat similar to something like `printf x:xs = print x >> printf xs`), it doesn't say anything at all about what kind of code the compiler will turn it into.

Comment: Bjarne's words simply mean that the function template instantiations are done at compile time. He's not talking about whether or not the calls to them will be inlined.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, and templates are specific to C++.  - But we talking about C++.

Comment: One important thing to note, is that it's not really recursive at runtime.  In this example, `printf<int, int>(char*, int, int)` is completely separate from `printf<int>(char*, int)` at runtime.

Comment: @Dave S  you talk about this http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#variadic-templates or this http://tinyurl.com/qc8hmpa example? I'm not sure that understand you. Are you talking about printf in source code, or about all that printf's, which compiler generate for each pack of arguments?

Comment: I was talking about the Strostrup example.  In your example, it's similar.  `f<int, int, int, int, int>` (5 args) calls `f<int, int, int, int>` (4 args) and so on, until it calls the 1 argument non-template version.  The template tells the compiler how to generate all of the versions of `f` with different arguments, but at runtime, they are all separate.  The compiler is allowed to optimize some of the calls out, but that will depend on the settings and the compiler.

Comment: @tower120: Why do you say "clang keeps it recursive"? In the clang output with -O2 and -O3, the compiled code looks just like gcc's, afaics.

Comment: I see no recursion at all at the clang's assembly. Where are you seeing recursion?

Comment: You are right, its my fault - in this example it compile it as gcc. But I can swear, that somehow I force clang to compile like gcc, but with jmp's instead of call's. May be there was some mistake of mine. Nevertheless question was rather - "Does compilers HAVE to substitute template recursiuon with plain code?". And I got answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bjarne's comment about compile-time recursion referred to the way that the templates are evaluated, not the way that the generated code would work.  For example, consider these templates:

```
template <typename... Args> struct Length;
template <> struct Length<> {
    static const size_t value = 0;
};
template <typename First, typename... Rest> struct Length {
    static const size_t value = 1 + Length<Rest>::value;
};
```

Here, if we instantiate `Length<int, int, int, int>` then

- `Length<int, int, int, int>` instantiates
- `Length<int, int, int>`, which instantiates
- `Length<int, int>`, which instantiates
- `Length<int>`, which instantiates
- `Length<>`

This process is a purely functional recursive expansion of the templates, which Bjarne was referring to.  It's the *process of expanding the templates to generate code* that's recursive and done at compile-time, rather than the *actual code generated* that would be unrolled inside the compiler.  The C++ compiler is free to optimize code however it sees fit as long as it doesn't change the underlying meaning of the code.  If you have a recursive function that uses this style of compile-time recursion, the compiler *might* optimize it, but there's no guarantee that it will.  The C++ standard doesn't give any restrictions on what sorts of optimizations are permissible or impermissible and just describes the required behavior, so there's no rules about this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, compiler even not have to calculate Length::value in your example at compile time? And all this optimisations around templates, is just due to compilers good will, which calculate const values at runtime? :))

Comment: @tower120- The compiler, I believe, does need to compute `Length::value` at compile-time because the constant needs to be initialized to a value for other purposes (if it's used in a `switch` statement, for example, or to define the size of an array).  However, that sort of optimization is pretty common, whereas transforming a recursive routine into an iterative one isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just because he says "This is rather standard functional programming done at compile time" doesn't mean the resulting code generated is completely non-recursive at runtime. His statement doesn't mention runtime at all.

There's no mention as to what a compiler should generate for execution at runtime. The only way to do away with the recursiveness of variadic template functions is for all the recursive calls to be inlined, tail-call optimized and/or for the compiler to somehow rearrange the code into a loop. So this is entirely compiler dependent.